# How do I set up a PayPal checkout

Tags: javascript, node.js, paypal, checkout

I'm wanting to set up a PayPal checkout button so my customers can buy goods using PayPal.
I want a solution that relies on the server and it just the client side.

I have been to the PayPal website and I have found all kinds of methods to enable the setting up of the API but I don't know which one to choose and the site does not explain much so I'm hopping you could tell me which method I should use to set it up?

Thanks

Comment: they don't have Bot Robots to ask?

Answer (score 0):

If you need a Checkout button, one of these demo patterns should get you started

[Option #1: No server-side code needed.](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client)

[Option #2: Requires server-side code for payment setup and capture.](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server)